# reader.onload not working on android

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have been tracking down the bug in my project, works on iOS and desktop browsers, fails silently on android.

I think it might have to do with my FileReader?
any insights are appreciated!

```
function handleImage(e) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        alert("alert 2");
        images.length = 0;
        images.push(img);
        imageLoaded = true;
        $('#changePhoto').removeClass('hidden');
        img.xPos = w / 2;
        img.yPos = h / 2;
        img.initWidth = img.width;
        img.initHeight = img.height;
        img.currentWidth = scale(img.initHeight, viewableArea, img.initWidth);
        img.currentHeight = viewableArea;
        if (img.currentWidth < viewableArea) {
            img.currentWidth = viewableArea;
            img.currentHeight = scale(img.initWidth, viewableArea, img.initHeight);
        }
        img.initAngle = 0;
        img.angle = 0;
    };
    img.src = event.target.result;
};
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
```

}

Comment: How did you solve it? I don't have requestAnimationFrame in my project. I am facing the same problem with android.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out requestAnimationFrame was my issue, I added this shim, and that solved it:
https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671